# VB Script ActiveX Task for SQL 2000 DTS Package

Tags: sql, vbscript, activex, dts

I'm trying to load data from an external csv file that needs to be massaged before being inserted into a SQL table.  Reading the file is fine, but when I try to loop through the stream and load an array using the SPLIT function I get a "Expected End of Statement" error.

```
Do While Not txtFile.AtEndOfStream

    strText = txtFile.ReadLine

    Dim dataArray() As String = Split(strText, ",")    -- Here's where it breaks

    ...

    build sql statement to insert using the zero based array

    RS.Open strSQL, dbConn, adOpenKeyset

Loop

txtFile.Close
```

I've looked at the BOL and MSDN, but I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBScript does not support typed variables.  VBScript does not support assigning a value in the Dim statement.  Use:-

```
Dim dataArray()
dataArray = Split(strText, ",")
```

However having said that since this is DTS task why aren't you creating a text csv data source in the transfrom rather than manually creating VBScript code to consume the CSV.

Comment: Thanks Anthony.  This worked and the "Part Duex" question I thought was something related and found out that I had not programmed the header for the CSV file correctly.

Answer (score 1):

From memory SQL 2k DTS uses vb scripts so no types.

```
Dim dataArray = split(strText,",")
```